# Using a [file] datasource with WordDocument.MailMerge

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-office, ms-word, office-interop

I get sent a log file each time this error happens, so it is definitely happening, I just haven't been able to find out how to reproduce it, or why its occurring.

I merge a `Word` document with a .dat file (through `vb.net`), my code that does the merge is simple:

```
document.WordDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(document.MergeFilePath, wdOpenFormatText, , , False)
```

`document.MergeFilePath` points to a local physical .dat file that contains a `datasource` for the document to use.

On certain clients, this (intermittently) causes an error, some errors are different, but most are `Exception: Word was unable to open the data source.`

I have tried checking the following properties, when the document is merging, to ensure that they are correctly set / in the correct state before attempting to set the `datasource`:
`Application.PrintPreview` | Changed the `ActiveWindow.View.Type` | (from wdReadingView) | `Options.AllowReadingMode`.

Again, on my side this is all working perfectly fine and I haven't been able to get any errors - although I know they are occurring.

My log file has this in it:

- Office version: Office2013
- Word ViewType: wdNormalView
- Word PrintPreview: False
- Word AllowReadingMode: False

**Exception details:
Stack Trace: at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn) at [PROJECT PATH].MergeDocument(Document& [document Object]) in [PROJECT Path]\FILENAME.vb:line 695**

Things to note:

- I've noticed it seems to only be on `Office2013` (used to be all versions), but
  seems the above changes fixed 2016).
- I think it has to do with a document (or multiple documents) being
  in a `readMode` state at some point
- Something must be happening where it 'locks' certain properties and hence,
  we are unable to update the `datasource` on the document.

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your dat file created by another process immediately before it is used by Word?

Comment: @bibadia not immediately, but yes - it is generated within the same process, I have confirmed that the file is created correctly, and contains the correct info - I have taken the EXACT same files that the user tries to merge, and I can merge them correctly (generally on the 2nd / 3rd attempt after getting this error, the user can merge successfully).

Comment: I don't have a solution, but just wonder if it is also a problem with 2013 that the dat file creator is failing to release a lock of some kind. (I have seen a number of reports of this kind of thing when the data file was generated from Access, for example).

Comment: The fact that this is now only affecting Office 2013 makes me have the same concerns, but how to prove it.

Comment: Can you for example introduce a delay (experimentally) between the point where the .dat is created and the point where Word tries to open it? What *is* creating the .dat?

Comment: You write: "we are unable to update the datasource on the document". Does this mean the previous data source is still attached to the document when you call `OpenDataSource`? You might consider setting the document to *not* be a mail merge document before calling this method. That will unlink the data source. Calling `OpenDataSource` will turn it back into a "normal" mail merge document. To unlink: `Document.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = Word.WdMailMergeMainDocType.wdNotAMergeDocument`

Comment: @bibadia Sorry for the delay - the .dat file gets created from a 3rd party app and sent to the main app, because of that, i'm not sure how the delay would help, especially as we get a 'new' .dat file each document.

Comment: @CindyMeister By that quote I mean, we load a new instance of Word, then assign a NEW datasource using the above method - which sets the document's datasource. The un-linking rings a bell, and I think we may have already tried that, although I will give it a go and see if it helps.

Comment: @CindyMeister Just got another log with this error (I have seen it a few times): `The OpenDataSource method or property is not available because the object refers to a protected area of the document`

Comment: Aha! Is this information in this article relevant: http://blogs.msmvps.com/wordmeister/2013/02/22/word2013bug-not-available-for-reading/

Comment: @CindyMeister That's a very interesting article, thanks for sharing, I'll give it a go... Although I currently have this code in place; 
`If Word.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type = WordViewType.wdReadingView Then                            Word.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type = WordViewType.wdNormalView`

Comment: @CindyMeister Scratch that, just checked the code, I actually already have this in place: 
`If My.HostApplication.OfficeVersion = MicrosoftOfficeVersions.Office2013 Then
Word.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type = WordViewType.wdPrintView...`

Comment: "protected area of the document" could mean: 1) Some kind of document protection has been applied, such as "read-only" or for forms 2) If the document is being opened "sandboxed", which could happen if it's coming from a non-trusted location; the user would see a message bar with a button to "enable content" or similar - in the object model "ProtectedViewWindow"

Comment: @Hexie: the rationale for introducing a delay is that an intermittent problem sometimes indicates a timing problem where the application that creates the .dat does not release the resource (or Windows or the server operating system, if the file is located on a server) does not release it. It doesn't really matter whether the .dat has been overwritten or has been created for the first time - it's whether or not it is available to be opened that counts. (It won't necessarily solve the problem - it's just something worth trying in an effort to pin down the problem.)

Comment: @bibadia Fair enough, I dont see any harm in adding a delay to open the .dat file - I'll let you know if it helps.

Comment: @CindyMeister Yeah that's pretty much how I understood it.. There isn't something that was possibly introduced only for Office 2013 that affects this but not other office(s)? I just find it weird that the other Office's were resolved with the changing view solution, yet 2013 still battles.